# regular expression for multiple filenames

Tags: regex, filenames

I have some files like that
15.58.55.ser  16.22.20.ser  16.36.23.ser  16.40.13.ser  16.59.41.ser  17.05.08.ser  17.14.40.ser  18.14.40.ser  18.20.43.ser
I want to replace these filenames with the following format
image_1.ser  image_2.ser ....

I don't know how to achieve it.

please give me some advice.

Comment: Please specify what platform are your trying to do the batch rename on (Windows/Linux?).

Answer (score 0):

The regex is quite simple:

```
(?:\d{2}\.){3}ser
```

It matches two digits `\d{2}` and a dot `\.` three times `{3}`, ending in `ser`.

You can [see from RegExr](http://regexr.com?31icp) that is matches all of your test cases.

However, in order to know how to do the replacement, you'd have to specify a language that you're working with.

Answer (score 0):

Try this(If you need Java code)

```
String regex = "\\.ser";
fileName = "15.58.55.ser";
System.out.println(filename.replaceAll(fileName.split(regex)[0], "image_1"));
```

This is just for only one entry. If you want to replace multiple files, do it in For loop or whatever